# How can I use Navigator in the newest version of React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, url-routing

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';

import Component5 from './app/components/component5/component5.js';
import Component6 from './app/components/component6/component6.js';

export default class myproject extends Component {
  renderScene(route, navigator){
    switch(route.id){
      case 'component5':
        return(<Component5 navigator={navigator} title="component5" />)
      case 'component6':
        return(<Component6 navigator={navigator} title="component6" />) 
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{id:'component5'}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScreen={(route, routeStack) => Navigtator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}
      />
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('myproject', () => myproject);
```

When I run it, it throws this error:

[image]

First of all, why `Navigator` is deprecated in the latest version? And what should I do now? I hardly think installing a deprecated thing be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about navigator, use react-navigation.

link: https://reactnavigation.org

Comment: I see, thank you, upvote. Just what do you think about `router-flux` ?

Comment: Hi, I can't give any comment on router-flux as I didn't use it before. But if you want to find a new navigation solution, I will recommend react-navigation. It's kind of 'official' navigation solution for react-native and pretty stable.

Comment: Ah, just what you mean *react-navigation* exactly? The one you linked in your question or [this](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) ?

Comment: yes, the one I provided in the link. it's react-navigation, not 'react-native-navigation'

Comment: forget about react-navigation, try react-native-navigation https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/